# Iterate over each sibling element

Tags: javascript, jquery, class, selector

**Context:**
I'm building a form and script which will perform an ajax query, based on clicking a specific button. There are multiple div blocks with elements of the same class, and based on the div block in which, a button is clicked, different forms will be processed.

As part of beginning the program, I have started with an apparently simple jQuery call.

I'm trying to add an onclick event to a specific class, and then trying to get the CSS value of the siblings of that element.

**Error:**
I'm getting an error stating that `TypeError: this.siblings is undefined`.

**Question:** What is the proper way to iterate over siblings of an element using jQuery?

My code:

**HTML:**

```
<a class="btn LiveStatsBtn"><span class="btn-label">Get Stats now</span> </a>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
$(document).ready (function()
{ 
    $('.LiveStatsBtn').click(function(){
        this.siblings.each( function () {
            var tx=this.css();
            alert(tx);
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 28, accepted):

In a jQuery event handler, `this` refers to the DOM element, and is not a jQuery object. You have to wrap it in one:

```
$(this).siblings().each(function() {
  // ...
});
```

Also note that "siblings" is a function, so you have to call it to get a new jQuery object that wraps the element siblings.

Answer (score 2):

`siblings` is a function, so it needs parentheses:

```
$(document).ready (function()
{ 
    $('.LiveStatsBtn').click(function(){
        $(this).siblings().each( function () {
            var tx=$(this).css();
            alert(tx);
        });
    });
});
```

http://api.jquery.com/siblings/